# Regex: "password must have at least 3 of the 4 of the following"

Tags: regex, passwords

I'm a Regex newbie, and so far have only used it for simple things, like "must be a number or letter". Now I have to do something a bit more complex.

I need to use it to validate a password, which must be 8-16 characters, free of control/non-printing/non-ASCII characters, and must have at least three of the following:

- one capital letter
- one lowercase letter
- one number 0-9
- one symbol character ($, %, &, etc.)

I'm thinking what I have to do is write something like "one capital letter, lowercase letter and number, OR one capital letter, lowercase letter and one symbol, OR one capital letter, one number or one symbol, OR...." to cover all possible "3 out of 4" combinations, but that seems excessive. Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Is there a good reason why you can't just simplify your requirements and require all four conditions?

Comment: Yes. Don't use regex. Regex is a powerful tool, just as much as a hammer is powerful. Yet if you try to screw in a screw with a hammer, it's gonna take a while...

Comment: My gut says this might be for a class assignment - because in practice, limiting the length of a password makes it a lot easier to crack. That said, you'll find it a lot more performant to just use `indexOf()` (or your language equivalent) to determine if one of the required characters is in it.

Comment: Excellent point, you're right, there's no particular reason why I can't require all four conditions. Remus, thanks for that tip. I suppose passwords don't need a max length.

Comment: @brandonscript, I came here because a server tool (Atlassian Crowd) uses a regex format just like this to control password formats, and there is no other option. So not necessarily a class assignment. And at my company, 3 of 4 conditions is the requirement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to check all of the five conditions separately. However, I assume there is a reason you want a regex, here you go:

```
/^((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\$\%\&])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\$\%\&])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[\$\%\&])).{8,16}$/
```

Explanation:

- We want to match the whole thing, hence we surround it with `^$`
- `.{n,m}` matches between `n` and `m` characters (8 and 16 in our case).
- The general way you can check if a string contains something, without actually matching it is by using positive lookahead `(?=.*X)`, where `X` is the thing you want to check. For example, if you want to make sure the string contains a lowercase letter you can do `(?=.*[a-z])`.
- If you want to check if a string contains `X`, `Y` and `Z`, but without actually matching them, you can use the previous recipe by appending the three lookaheads `(?=.*X)(?=.*Y)(?=.*Z)`
- We use the above to match three of the four things mentioned. We go through all possible combinations with `|`(or) - `cCD|cDS|CDS|CcS` (`c` = lowercase letter, `C` = capital letter, `D` = digit, `S` = special)

[See it in action](http://rubular.com/r/tPcR0v5rgV)

Comment: Thank you for also including a breakdown! I'd like to gain an understanding of Regex rather than just have someone do it for me.

Comment: great explanation ! just noticed the order is "cCD | CcS   |  CDS  |  cDS  " rather than "cCD|cDS|CDS|CcS" although I got the point. Thank you !

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do this is by checking each condition separately. Performance will suffer if you try to fit all conditional criteria into one expression (see the accepted answer). I also highly recommend against limiting the length of the password to 16 chars — this is extremely insecure for modern standards. Try something more like 64 chars, or even better, 128 — assuming your hashing architecture can handle the load.

You also didn't specify a language, but this is one way to do it in JavaScript:

```
var pws = [
    "%5abCdefg",
    "&5ab",
    "%5abCdef",
    "5Bcdwefg",
    "BCADLKJSDSDFlk"
];

function pwCheck(pw) {
    var criteria = 0;
    if (pw.toUpperCase() != pw) {
        // has lower case letters
        criteria++;
    }
    if (pw.toLowerCase() != pw) {
        // has upper case letters
        criteria++;
    }
    if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/.test(pw) === false) {
        // has special characters
        criteria++;
    }
    if (/\d/.test(pw) === true) {
        // has numbers
        criteria++;
    }
    // returns true if 3 or more criteria was met and length is appropriate
    return (criteria >= 3 && pw.length >= 8 && pw.length <= 16);
}

pws.forEach(function(pw) {
    console.log(pw + ": " + pwCheck(pw).toString());
});
```

Comment: If you want to make a case for performance you should do this in one go by looping through the characters in the string. Instead here we have four operations with linear complexity, which is the same amount of operations needed by a regex solution. However, this is indeed the right approach, if you are not limited to using regex, because it is more readable than both of the alternatives.

Comment: Agreed - I know it can be simplified and performance improved, but I wanted to show the logic behind the approach vs. a compact solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if its a iOS thing, the regex with "d" for digits [0-9] wasn't working as expected, example String that had issues =  "AAAAAA1$"

The fix below works fine in Objective-C and Swift 3

```
   ^((?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])|(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9])|(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9])|(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9])).{8,16}$
```